# KeyNotFoundException: Could not find view for WCFManager.ViewModels.SettingsViewModel

Tags: android, navigation, mvvmcross

I try to navigate in MvvmCross by using the following from my MainViewModel.cs

```
public IMvxAsyncCommand GoToSettingsPage => new MvxAsyncCommand(() => _navService.Navigate<SettingsViewModel>());
```

My SettingsViewModel.cs looks like this

```
public class SettingsViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    private readonly IMvxNavigationService _navService;

    public SettingsViewModel(IMvxNavigationService _navService)
    {
        this._navService = _navService;
    }

    public override Task Initialize() => base.Initialize();

    public IMvxAsyncCommand GoToMainPage => new MvxAsyncCommand(() => _navService.Navigate<MainViewModel>());
}
```

And this is my SettingsView.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:minWidth="25px"
android:minHeight="25px">
<Button
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    local:MvxBind="Click GoToMainPage" />
</LinearLayout>
```

If I start up my App and load immediately into the SettingsViewModel instead of the MainViewModel, it works just fine. Navigating doesn't work though, I always get the following message:

```
System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: Could not find view for WCFManager.ViewModels.SettingsViewModel
```

I understand, that it can't find the associated view by the KeyNotFoundException, but I couldn't find any way to manually associate it and according to similar issues, it associates it automatically by name. Unfortunately the name is already right and I can find views when I load them straight from the start like this

```
[Activity]
public class MainView : MvxActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.MainView);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By writing my own question I realized how blind I was.
It isn't enough to have an .axml file for each View, you need to have a class for it too. I just copied the MainView class that I showed in the question and wrote SettingsView instead. Works fine.

```
[Activity]
public class SettingsView : MvxActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.SettingsView);
    }
}
```